# How do I format datetime data to fit google calendar api's date field?

Tags: python, date, google-calendar-api

Goal: create a Google Calendar event.

Blocker: the date formatting.

---

background: I'm trying to create a meal planner that takes recipes from a given database and creates events with their name in a google calendar. The database looks like this:

```
d = {'recipe_id': ['carrot salad', 'leek fritters'], 'meal_date': ['2020-05-28 22:28:01.204464+00:00', '2020-05-29 22:28:01.204464+00:00']}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

the meal date is a product of two

```
today_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
df['menu_date'] = today_date
df['menu_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['menu_date'])
df['meal_date'] = df['menu_date'] + df['meal'].apply(pd.offsets.Day)
```

Where 'meal' is just a number (1, 2, etc) and the last command just shifts today's date by that amount.

When I use the following code to upload to google calendar I get an error:

```
def myconverter(o):
    '''
    call the __str__ method of the datetime object that will return a string representation of the value
    ___

    shoutout: https://code-maven.com/serialize-datetime-object-as-json-in-python
    '''
    if isinstance(o, datetime.datetime):
        return o.__str__()

def add_to_calendar(df, calendar_id):
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Adding meals to calendar')

    for i, r in df.iterrows():
        event = {
        'summary': r.name,
        'description': r.meal_period,
        'start': {
            'date': json.dumps(r.meal_date, default=myconverter),
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
        },
        'end': {
            'date': json.dumps(r.meal_date, default=myconverter),
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
        }
        }
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId=calendar_id, body=event).execute()
```

running this code, I get the following error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/CALENDAR_ID/events?alt=json returned "Invalid value for: Invalid format: ""2020-05-28 22:28:01.204464+00:00""">
```

where CALENDAR_ID is my google calendar id.

If anyone knows how to fix this date issue using python code, this would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Modification points:

- If you want to use `start.date` and `end.date` as the all-day event, the format is required to be `yyyy-mm-dd`. In this case, timeZone is not required.
- If you want to use `start.dateTime` and `end.dateTime` as the all-day event, the format is required to be RFC3339. In this case, timeZone is required.

From above situations, when your script is modified, how about the following patterns?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `start.date` and `end.date` are used. For this, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
'start': {
    'date': json.dumps(r.meal_date, default=myconverter),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
},
'end': {
    'date': json.dumps(r.meal_date, default=myconverter),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}
```

#### To:

```
'start': {
    'date': 'date': parse(r.meal_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
},
'end': {
    'date': 'date': parse(r.meal_date).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `start.dateTime` and `end.dateTime` are used. For this, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
'start': {
    'date': json.dumps(r.meal_date, default=myconverter),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
},
'end': {
    'date': json.dumps(r.meal_date, default=myconverter),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}
```

#### To:

```
'start': {
    'dateTime': parse(r.meal_date).isoformat(),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
},
'end': {
    'dateTime': parse(r.meal_date).isoformat(),
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
}
```

### Note:

- In this modification, `from dateutil.parser import parse` is used.
- From your script, I couldn't see the scope you are using. So if the error related to the scope occurs, please use `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar` as the scope. At that time, please delete the file of `token.pickle` and reauthorize the scope. Please be careful this.

### Reference:

- [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)